# Communicate Rust pnet packets between threads using channels

Tags: multithreading, rust, pcap

I'm working on a simple Rust program that reads and parses network packets. For reading the network packets I'm using the [pnet libary](https://github.com/libpnet/libpnet).
Because the parsing may take some time I'm using two separate threads for reading and parsing the packets.

My idea now was to pass the read packages from the first thread to the second thread via message passing (using `mpsc::channel()`).
Here's a simplified version of my code which I wrote based on [the example given in the pnet doc](https://docs.rs/pnet/0.21.0/pnet/):

```
extern crate pnet;

use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;

use pnet::datalink;
use pnet::datalink::Channel::Ethernet;

fn main() {
    let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        for packet in receiver.recv() {
            println!("{:?}", packet)
        }
    });

    let interface = datalink::interfaces().into_iter()
        .find(|interface| interface.name == "enp5s0")
        .unwrap();
    let (_, mut package_receiver) =
        match datalink::channel(&interface, Default::default()) {
            Ok(Ethernet(tx, rx)) => (tx, rx),
            _ => panic!()
        };

    loop {
        match package_receiver.next() {
            Ok(packet) => {
                // sender.send("foo"); // this works fine
                sender.send(packet);
            }
            _ => panic!()
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine for sending primitive types or Strings over the channel, but not for the network packets. When I try to send a packet to the parser thread via the channel I get the following compiler error:

```
error[E0597]: `*package_receiver` does not live long enough                                                                   
--> src/main.rs:28:15                                                                                                       
|                                                                                                                          
28 |         match package_receiver.next() {                                                                                  
|               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough                                                  
...                                                                                                                           
36 | }                                                                                                                        
| - borrowed value only lives until here                                                                                   
|                                                                                                                          
= note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

I'm pretty new to Rust and would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

`packet` is `&[u8]` type, with some lifetime `'a` that is also same as that of the reference taken to `package_receiver` in the `next()` call.  The `next()` definition with lifetimes will look like this:

```
fn next(&'a mut self) -> Result<&'a [u8]>
```

You `send` the `&[u8]` to a thread. But the thread can outlive the references you send to it, leading to dangling references. As a result the compiler complains that they need to have `'static` lifetime.`"foo"` works because it is `&'static str`.

One way would be to take the ownership of the data and then send it as a value to another thread.

```
Ok(packet) => {
   // sender.send("foo"); // this works fine
   sender.send(packet.to_owned());
}
```

You can also have a look at using scoped threads with [crossbeam](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.5.0/crossbeam/thread/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The *package_receiver.next()* call is defined as:

```
pub trait DataLinkReceiver: Send {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Result<&[u8]>;
}
```

And the mspc::Sender defines send as:

```
pub fn send(&self, t: T) -> Result<(), SendError<T>>
```

So package_receiver.next() returns a result containing a reference to a slice of bytes, *&[u8]*. So when you then call *sender.send(packet);* that's saying you want to send the reference to the other thread. However, the match scope for package_receiver.next() doesn't promise that the reference lives longer than the end of the scope. So the other thread can't be guaranteed that the reference is still valid at the time it's accessing that data.

The str works because it's a static lifetime string. That memory will always be valid to read no matter what thread reads it.

If you change your call to:

```
sender.send(Vec::from(packet))
```

This creates a Vec variable, copies the packet slice into the new memory, then passes ownership of that variable to the other thread. This guarantees that the other receiving thread will always have clear access to that data. Because the ownership is clearly passed, the code in the receiving thread is known to the compiler as where the lifetime of received Vec variables ends.

There will also be some miscellaneous errors about using the result of the .send() which could be taken care of with something like this:

```
if sender.send(Vec::from(packet)).is_err() {
    println!("Send error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here do a great job of explaining why this happens, and it seems `EthernetPacket` (which derives the packet macro) is simply a wrapper around a reference of bytes. To make a "new" `EthernetPacket` variable from the reference of bytes, one could do the following:

```
let packet = EthernetPacket::owned(packet.to_owned()).unwrap();
sender.send(packet).unwrap();
```

This will clone the packet bytes and make send them through the channel.
Documentation for `EthernetPacket::owned` can be found [here](https://docs.rs/pnet/latest/pnet/packet/ethernet/struct.EthernetPacket.html#method.owned).